# Indent paragraph both on the left and right without any external packages

Tags: indentation, paragraphs

I am following the AAAI 19 Template from https://aaai.org/Conferences/AAAI-19/aaai19call/ where a text abstract is supposed to be formatted in a way that it is indented 10pt to the left and 10pt to the right.

Currently, I have the following:

```
\hangindent=10pt \emph{text} \\
```

This indents the left part. I know I can indent right with *\hangindent=-10pt* but if I combine both only the last one is used.

I know there is *\leftskip* and *\rightskip* commands, but if I use them before my paragraph, they suddently apply to not just the paragraph but the whole text afterwards.

```
\leftskip=10pt \rightskip=10pt \emph{text} \\
some other text that also gets left and right margins, which it shouldn't.
```

I saw an example where you can use *\addtolength* command to set indents to one paragraph only, but the template forbids using the *\addtolength* command in the paper. So, something like this is apparently not allowed:

```
{\addtolength{\leftskip=10pt\rightskip=10pt}{mytext}} % don't remember the exact example
```

*\setlength* is also forbidden.

I can't find any other solution.

EDIT: I also tried groups:

```
\begingroup \leftskip=10pt \rightskip=10pt \emph{text} \endgroup \\
in this case nothing happens at all, indents don't work
```

Comment: Did you try `\leftskip`, `\rightskip` and the paragraph in  a group?

Comment: @Bernard the grouping does not do anything at all in my case. Maybe I did it wrong. I added an edit with an example

Comment: And really all packages are forbidden? Because the `quoting` package has tools for that.

Comment: @Bernard Don't see that one blacklisted. Can you, please give me an example of how I could do it with _quoting_ package?

Comment: Very simple: `\begin{quoting}[leftmargin=10pt, rightmargin=10pt] ... end{quoting}`. You see more details on the parameters in the documentation.

Comment: After changing `\leftskip` and `\rightskip` to affect a paragraph (they affect whole paragraphs at a time), the change stays in force until you reset them to `0pt` afterwards.

Comment: The page you link to has a template for LaTeX submissions. You should use that. I can't see where the parameters you mention are specified.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`\leftskip` and `\rightskip` have to be *un*done after you are through with them.  Note that they affect whole paragraphs and cannot be used to change indentation for *parts* of a paragraph.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]

\leftskip1cm\relax
\rightskip1cm\relax
\lipsum[2]

\leftskip0cm\relax
\rightskip0cm\relax
\lipsum[3]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Here it is as the `myindent` environment:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\newenvironment{myindent}
{\par\leftskip1cm\relax\rightskip1cm\relax}
{\par\leftskip0cm\relax\rightskip0cm\relax}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
\begin{myindent}
\lipsum[2]
\end{myindent}
\lipsum[3]
\end{document}
```

Comment: If you show how to make this an environment (which will remove the need to undo the values) I think this will solve the OPs problem.

Answer (score 4):

There is an alternative:

```
{\leftskip=1cm\relax
 \rightskip=1cm\relax
 text
 \par}
```

Comment: There are numerous instances of this use of commands in the literature, that is without the \relax command, and I have no problems using them that way myself; what could be the necessity for this addition ?